# What's the proper way to recurse in LLVM assembly?

Tags: pointers, recursion, assembly, llvm

Here is my program in its entirety; I'm using a silly recursive algorithm to familiarize myself with LLVM assembly:

```
declare void @print_int(i32)

define i32 @rec_add(i32 %a, i32 %b) {
entry:
    %tmp1 = icmp eq i32 %a, 0
    br i1 %tmp1, label %done, label %recurse
    recurse:
        %tmp2 = sub i32 %a, 1
        %tmp3 = add i32 %b, 1
        ret i32 @rec_add(i32 %tmp2, i32 %tmp3)
    done:
        ret i32 %b
}

define i32 @main() {
    %tmp4 = i32 4;
    %tmp5 = i32 1;
    %cast = call i32 @rec_add(i32 %tmp4, i32 %tmp5)
    call void @print_int(i32 %cast)
}
```

When I compile this program with `$ llvm-as rec_add.ll`, I receive this error message:

```
llvm-as: rec_add.ll:10:11: error: global variable reference must have pointer type
                ret i32 @rec_add(i32 %tmp2, i32 %tmp3)
                        ^
```

I do not understand what this error message means, because my program has no global variables. And I know for a fact that LLVM assembly does not require pointers as its arguments.

Comment: I don't know LLVM assembly, but you sure you don't need a `call` in there, probably as another statement? Otherwise it looks like you're trying to return the function, which you can't do except indirectly through a pointer.

Comment: @RossRidge: IDK LLVM asm either, but that didn't seem to work without a temporary with no ill effect in code-gen.  Nice catch on the missing `call`.  I agree that the OP's syntax was probably trying to return a function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't even know llvm-as existed, but assigning the recursive call result to a variable worked.  Then return that.  This optimizes away even at `-O0`.  See Oak's answer/comments for correct terminology.

```
define i32 @rec_add(i32 %a, i32 %b) {
entry:
    %tmp1 = icmp eq i32 %a, 0
    br i1 %tmp1, label %done, label %recurse
    recurse:
        %tmp2 = sub i32 %a, 1
        %tmp3 = add i32 %b, 1
        %tmp4 = call i32 @rec_add(i32 %tmp2, i32 %tmp3)
        ret i32 %tmp4
    done:
        ret i32 %b
}
```

compiles to a recursive call with `clang-3.8 -O0 -S -o-`.

With `clang-3.8 -Wall -O3 rec-add.ll -S -masm=intel -o-`, llvm sees through the recursion:

```
rec_add:                                # @rec_add
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
```

Your `main` doesn't compile:

```
rec-add.ll:17:13: error: expected instruction opcode
    %tmp4 = i32 4;
```

This does the trick:

```
define i32 @main() {
    %cast = call i32 @rec_add(i32  4, i32 1)
    call void @print_int(i32 %cast)
    ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: My `main` compiles if I remove the variables and add `ret i32 0` (return 0) to the end.

Comment: Downvoting because although this is correct, your terminology and explanation are off, which can be confusing. `%tmp` is not a temporary, it's an instruction - and anyway the problem is using `ret` and `call` together, and not the lack of "using a temporary", see my answer.

Comment: @Oak: thanks for the terminology correction.  Trial-and-error is not the usual basis for my answers :P

Answer (score 2):

Unlike high-level languages, LLVM instructions cannot be composed of compound expressions. So this is not a valid instruction:

```
ret i32 @rec_add(i32 %tmp2, i32 %tmp3)
```

You can either do `ret` or `call`, not both at once*. What you actually written here is trying to return the *address* of the function - and that is of course not an `i32`, hence the type error. Instead, you need to do something like:

```
%something = call i32 @rec_add(i32 %tmp2, i32 %tmp3)
ret i32 %something
```

<sub>* Well you can do compound stuff if those are [constant expressions](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions), but that's not the case here.</sub>